# Cakephp 2.5 Order by query

Tags: mysql, json, cakephp

i am trying to apply order by query on my publication table and then applying json encode, its works fine before json encode. and even after json encode in window, but on live server json encoding is not working, can anyone plz guide me where i am doing mistake. 
the code is here below

```
    public function articles($offset = null) {
    $order=array('Publication.id' =>'DESC');
    $total2 = $this->Publication->find('all', array('limit' => 10, 'offset' => $offset * 10, 'order' => $order));
    echo json_encode($total2); die();

}
```

Comment: If the problem is with json_encode then check your PHP version. Use an alternative custom function from http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php instead of json_encode if the function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Ananth thanks for your feedback, in the same controller with different actions i am using json_encode, its working fine everywhere beside of this action.

Comment: Give it a try using $total2 = $this->Publication->find('all', array('limit' => 10, 'offset' => $offset * 10, 'order' => 'Publication.id DESC'));

Comment: @Ananth, yes i have already tried this, even this is not working :(

Comment: If you write print_r($total2); before json_encode() does it print the result array correctly?

Comment: @Ananth yes in print_r($total2); its shows the correct results

Comment: Okay can you give a link to the live server?

Comment: Add print_r($total2); to your question and sample of expected output...

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for everyone who showed their concern to help me out, i have fixed this problem, the problem was that i am using cakephp, so in cakephp while using json encoding we need to add Requesthandler in the componenet  like public $components = array('RequestHandler');